# Isomorphism of $K\otimes_F F$ and $K$ where $F$ is a subfield of $K$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a subfield of the field $K$. Consider a function $T$ that does the following: $T(k\otimes f) = kf,$  for every $k\in K$ and $f\in F$. Since the map $(k,f)\mapsto kf$ is bilinear in $K\times F$, by the universal property $T$ extends uniquely to a linear map $T:K\otimes_F F\longrightarrow K$.

How can I show that this map is bijective? Thank you.

Comment: It is more generally true that for any ring $R$ and any $R$-algebra $S$, we have $S\otimes_RR\cong S$, or in other words, $R$ is the identity element for the operation $\otimes_R$ on $R$-algebras.

Comment: I've found that, when doing problems like this involving the tensor product, it's easier to build the inverse by hand. Surjectivity is usually not so bad, but the problem of showing injectivity becomes "Ok, so some sum of simple tensors is 0. Now what?" An explicit inverse is often not hard to construct and showing it's inverse to the given map is just a matter of applying properties of the tensor product to move some symbols around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should notice that every element in $K \otimes F$ is of the form $k \otimes 1$. This should be easy, since
$$\sum\limits_{\mbox{finite}} k_i \otimes f_i = \sum\limits_{\mbox{finite}} k_i \otimes f_i.1 = \sum\limits_{\mbox{finite}} k_if_i \otimes 1 = \left(\sum\limits_{\mbox{finite}} k_if_1 \right) \otimes 1$$

With that, injectivity can be proven easily. Surjectivity is kind of straight-forward.

Answer (score 7):

Exhibit the inverse map:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}K&\longrightarrow&K\otimes_FF\\[.1in]k&\longmapsto&k\otimes1\end{array}$$

Now, to show this is the inverse map, remember that $k\otimes f=fk\otimes 1$ in $K\otimes_F F$.